# wrong date when using dateByAddingTimeInterval

Tags: objective-c

whenever I try to add or subtract timeInterval to current date I also get a negative date. This is the code that I'm using in the debugger:

```
(lldb) po [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:30*24*60*60];
-5877520-03-03 -596:-31:-23 +0000
```

It doesn't matter if I use a positive or negative number as time interval, I always get a negative date.

I was using CuppertinoYankee in my project, but I removed the reference to it and got same result.

Hope someone could help me with this.

Kind regards

**UPDATE**
The output of the NSLog is:

```
2015-03-29 20:46:59:762 TestingProject[60975:607] start date: 
2015-03-29 20:46:59:763 TestingProject[60975:607] end date: 2015-04-28 18:46:59 +0000
```

and the code that produced that output is:

```
NSUInteger startDaysBefore = 30;
NSUInteger endDaysAfter = 30;

NSDate *startDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:(-startDaysBefore)*24*60*60];
NSDate *endDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:endDaysAfter*24*60*60];

NSLog(@"start date: %@", startDate);
NSLog(@"end date: %@", endDate);
```

Comment: And what is the result if you use NSLog?

Comment: Try this: `po [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:30.0*24*60*60]` (Note that I have written `30.0` instead of just `30`.) Does it work?

Comment: Hi @robmayoff, that worked perfectly. Please, post it as an Answer so I can check it as the solution. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: By the way, one would generally use `NSCalendar` and `dateByAddingComponents` (or in iOS 8, `dateByAddingUnit`). By adding 30*24*60*60, you're not reflecting daylight savings changes.

Comment: Actually I found that way after reading your answer, so I change my code for using NSCalendar instead of adding time interval. Nevertheless both of your answers solved my problem, so thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce this in Xcode 6.2 (6C131e) on Yosemite (10.10.2 (14C1514)), but my guess is you're using an older version of Xcode and it's messing up the argument type.

A time interval (`NSTimeInterval`) is a `double`. Your expression `30*24*60*60` has type `int`. My guess is that your Xcode doesn't recognize that `dateByAddingTimeInterval:` takes a `double` argument, so it's passing the argument as an `int`.

If you compute the argument as a `double`, Xcode will pass it as a `double`. The easiest way is to make one of the factors a `double`, like this:

```
po [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:30.0*24*60*60]
```

I agree with @Rob's comment that generally you should use an `NSCalendar` for calendrical calculations. Adding seconds sometimes gives the wrong answer.